# Convert Image JPG to GIF and print it into the tag IMG in BASE64

Tags: php, html, image, base64

This is my actual code, I have troubles related with the right visualization of the gif image generated on the fly for my php script. If I access directly to the gif image generated by the script the browser show it good but if I try from my current script through tag img, the browser couldn't show it.

Any suggest friends ?

```
<?php
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg( 'img/ejemplo-2.jpg' );
list( $width, $height ) = getimagesize( 'img/ejemplo-2.jpg' );
$tmp = imagecreatetruecolor( '300', '300');
imagecopyresampled( $tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, '300', '300', $width, $height );
$imagen = imagegif( $tmp, "filename.gif" );
$data   = "data:image/gif;base64," . base64_encode( file_get_contents( "filename.gif" ) );
?>

<img src="<?php echo $data; ?>" width="300" height="300" />
```

Comment: Which browser are you testing with?

Comment: Mozilla Firefox 3.6 over Mac OS X Snow Leopard, this example run well in my browser: http://diveintogreasemonkey.org/patterns/add-image.html

Comment: Is there any particular reason you must use the data URI scheme?  It isn't supported in all browsers, and you will be using a lot more bandwidth by base64 encoding the image data.  I'd strongly recommend referencing your PHP script as the img src, rather than just dumping the data right there.

Comment: I want to solver problems related with browser cache.

Comment: Edwin, browser cache should be managed with the appropriate HTTP headers.  See:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Opera 7.2+, Firefox, Safari, Netscape, and Mozilla support data URIs, Internet Explorer 5-7 do not. However, Internet Explorer 8 reportedly does, by passing the Acid2 test, making data URLs a viable alternative for embedding smaller decorative images. There are workarounds that you can use for older versions of Internet Explorer.

If you want to get round browser cache issues, append a random generated number onto the end of the img src :

```
<img src="test.jpg?12345" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much, was very easy after your suggest jejeje : )